# ratio from different condition in Group By clause SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table t with three columns, a, b, c. I want to calculate the number of a where b =1 over the number of a where b = 2 for every category in c. some Pseudo code is like: (mysql)

```
     select count(distinct a) where b = 1 / count(distinct a) where b = 2
     from t
     group by c
```

but this won't work in SQL, since the condition 'where' cannot add for every category in c in the clause group by c.

Comment: Can you include an example input and example output?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Did either of the answers help you @beimingxu?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which database you are using, so I'll assume it implements `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Also, you don't say what to do in case a division by zero could happen. Anyway, this query will get you the separate sums, so you can compute the division as needed:

```
select
  coalesce(x.c, y.c) as c
  coalesce(x.e, 0) as b1
  coalesce(y.f, 0) as b2
  case when y.f is null or y.f = 0 then -1 else x.e / y.f end
from (
  select c, count(distinct a) as e
  from t
  where b = 1
  group by c
) x
full join (
  select c, count(distinct a) as f
  from t
  where b = 2
  group by c
) y on x.c = y.c
```

Comment: my environment is mysql and there's no outer join. But I can still use left join, right join and union to accomplish the same task. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL:

```
create table test (a int, b int, c varchar(10));
insert into test values
(1, 1, 'food'), (2, 1, 'food'), (3, 1, 'food'),
(1, 2, 'food'), (2, 2, 'food'),
(1, 1, 'drinks'), (2, 1, 'drinks'), (2, 1, 'drinks'),
(1, 2, 'drinks')
;


select cat.c, cast(sum(b1_count) as decimal)/sum(b2_count), sum(b1_count), sum(b2_count) from
(select distinct c from test) as cat
left join 
(select c, count(distinct a) b1_count from test where b = 1 group by c) b1 on cat.c = b1.c
left join
(select c, count(distinct a) b2_count from test where b = 2 group by c) b2
  on cat.c = b2.c
group by cat.c;
```

**Result**

> ```
> c      | (No column name) | (No column name) | (No column name)
> :----- | ---------------: | ---------------: | ---------------:
> drinks |    2.00000000000 |                2 |                1
> food   |    1.50000000000 |                3 |                2
> ```

Examples:

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2003e0baa46bfbb197152b829ea57d2d
- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2003e0baa46bfbb197152b829ea57d2d
- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2003e0baa46bfbb197152b829ea57d2d

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
 select count(distinct case when b = 1 then a end) / count(distinct case when b = 2 then a end)
 from t
 group by c;
```

You don't mention your database, but some do integer division -- which can result in unexpected truncation.  You might want a `* 1.0 /` instead of `/` to for non-integer division.